# Modules not found when using express

Tags: javascript, typescript, express, npm, electron

I want to expose REST service in electron app and I want to use expressJS with electron, as tutorial states I added express and @types/express. I tried to expose a "get " but when I build and run it throws the following.

Ran with  `ng build --prod`

> ```
> ERROR in ./node_modules/cookie-signature/index.js
> Module not found: Error: Can't resolve 'crypto' in 'app\node_modules\cookie-signature'
> ERROR in ./node_modules/etag/index.js
> Module not found: Error: Can't resolve 'crypto' in 'app\node_modules\etag'
> ERROR in ./node_modules/destroy/index.js
> Module not found: Error: Can't resolve 'fs' in 'app\node_modules\destroy'
> ERROR in ./node_modules/etag/index.js
> Module not found: Error: Can't resolve 'fs' in 'app\node_modules\etag'
> ERROR in ./node_modules/express/lib/view.js
> Module not found: Error: Can't resolve 'fs' in 'app\node_modules\express\lib'
> ERROR in ./node_modules/mime/mime.js
> Module not found: Error: Can't resolve 'fs' in 'app\node_modules\mime'
> ERROR in ./node_modules/send/index.js
> Module not found: Error: Can't resolve 'fs' in 'app\node_modules\send'
> ERROR in ./node_modules/express/lib/application.js
> Module not found: Error: Can't resolve 'http' in 'app\node_modules\express\lib'
> ERROR in ./node_modules/express/lib/response.js
> Module not found: Error: Can't resolve 'http' in 'app\node_modules\express\lib'
> ERROR in ./node_modules/express/lib/request.js
> Module not found: Error: Can't resolve 'http' in 'app\node_modules\express\lib'
> ERROR in ./node_modules/express/lib/request.js
> Module not found: Error: Can't resolve 'net' in 'app\node_modules\express\lib'
> ERROR in ./node_modules/content-disposition/index.js
> Module not found: Error: Can't resolve 'path' in 'app\node_modules\content-disposition'
> ERROR in ./node_modules/express/lib/view.js
> Module not found: Error: Can't resolve 'path' in 'app\node_modules\express\lib'
> ERROR in ./node_modules/express/lib/response.js
> Module not found: Error: Can't resolve 'path' in 'app\node_modules\express\lib'
> ERROR in ./node_modules/express/lib/application.js
> Module not found: Error: Can't resolve 'path' in 'app\node_modules\express\lib'
> ERROR in ./node_modules/mime/mime.js
> Module not found: Error: Can't resolve 'path' in 'app\node_modules\mime'
> ERROR in ./node_modules/mime-types/index.js
> Module not found: Error: Can't resolve 'path' in 'app\node_modules\mime-types'
> ERROR in ./node_modules/send/index.js
> Module not found: Error: Can't resolve 'path' in 'app\node_modules\send'
> ERROR in ./node_modules/serve-static/index.js
> Module not found: Error: Can't resolve 'path' in 'app\node_modules\serve-static'
> ERROR in ./node_modules/destroy/index.js
> Module not found: Error: Can't resolve 'stream' in 'app\node_modules\destroy'
> ERROR in ./node_modules/iconv-lite/lib/streams.js
> Module not found: Error: Can't resolve 'stream' in 'app\node_modules\iconv-lite\lib'
> ERROR in ./node_modules/iconv-lite/lib/extend-node.js
> Module not found: Error: Can't resolve 'stream' in 'app\node_modules\iconv-lite\lib'
> ERROR in ./node_modules/send/index.js
> Module not found: Error: Can't resolve 'stream' in 'app\node_modules\send'
> ERROR in ./node_modules/body-parser/lib/read.js
> Module not found: Error: Can't resolve 'zlib' in 'app\node_modules\body-parser\lib'
> ```

It's the first time i wanna do this kind of things so excuse me if I don't know smth...

package.json :

```
> {
  "name": "angular-electron",
  "version": "0.0.0",
  "main": "main.js",
  "scripts": {
    "ng": "ng",
    "start": "ng serve",
    "build": "ng build",
    "test": "ng test",
    "lint": "ng lint",
    "e2e": "ng e2e",
    "electron": "electron .",
    "electron-build": "ng build --prod && electron ."
  },
  "private": true,
  "dependencies": {
    "@angular/animations": "^6.0.4",
    "@angular/common": "^6.0.4",
    "@angular/compiler": "^6.0.4",
    "@angular/core": "^6.0.4",
    "@angular/forms": "^6.0.4",
    "@angular/http": "^6.0.4",
    "@angular/platform-browser": "^6.0.4",
    "@angular/platform-browser-dynamic": "^6.0.4",
    "@angular/router": "^6.0.4",
    "@types/express": "^4.16.0",
    "angular-svg-round-progressbar": "^2.0.0",
    "core-js": "^2.5.4",
    "express": "^4.16.3",
    "js-sha256": "^0.9.0",
    "rxjs": "^6.2.0",
    "rxjs-compat": "^6.2.0",
    "zone.js": "^0.8.26"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@angular-devkit/build-angular": "~0.6.6",
    "@angular/cli": "~6.0.7",
    "@angular/compiler-cli": "^6.0.4",
    "@angular/language-service": "^6.0.4",
    "@types/jasmine": "~2.8.6",
    "@types/jasminewd2": "~2.0.3",
    "@types/node": "~8.9.4",
    "codelyzer": "~4.2.1",
    "electron": "^2.0.2",
    "jasmine-core": "~2.99.1",
    "jasmine-spec-reporter": "~4.2.1",
    "karma": "~1.7.1",
    "karma-chrome-launcher": "~2.2.0",
    "karma-coverage-istanbul-reporter": "~2.0.0",
    "karma-jasmine": "~1.1.1",
    "karma-jasmine-html-reporter": "^0.2.2",
    "protractor": "~5.3.0",
    "ts-node": "~5.0.1",
    "tslint": "~5.9.1",
    "typescript": "~2.7.2"
  }
}
```

The project worked perfectly untill I've added the express part, it worked.

```
  var app = express()

  app.get('/', function (req, res) {
    res.send('Hello World')
  })
```

Comment: woah man, that block of error messages broke my screen. Seems like you didn't install all the packages, have you tried `npm install --save` if you are using a `NodeJS` version before 8.

Comment: NodeJS 8.11.3 and tried that npm install --save. Nothing different than what I've shown :(

Comment: is your file named `Package.json` or `package.json` because it's supposed to be with a lower letter. Another thing might be that you don't have the right path to `NodeJS` in local variables.

Comment: Sorry for the misunderstanding, I'll change that right away, It's package.json.

Comment: try to remove node_modules and package-lock.json and reinstall deps with npm i

Comment: Tried it, nothing different

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You have now 2 applications in your solution:

1) client application: angular which runs in a browser environment

2) server application: express which runs in a node environment

When building the angular application (using ng build) you have to make sure you don't include the express application files in the angular build. The node modules used by express are not available in a browser environment.

You can do:

1) move the express source out of the src folder into project root

```
// server.js
var express = require('express');
var app = express();

app.use(express.static('dist')); // or where the output of the ng-build is placed

app.listen(3000, function() { console.log('Server running on port 3000'); });
```

2) run `ng-build`

3) run `node server.js` from project root. this will keep running

4) go to `localhost:3000` and see your app

Comment: Thanks dude, saved my day twice now!

Answer (score 8):

I have tried every solution available on the internet and nothing worked actually. My project was using **angular universal** and it was express to render the application on the server side.
On one morning suddenly I started getting this error and my project was not running.I tried the
browser :{
"fs": false
}
fix suggested by someone. That even did not work. It took my entire day.
I started analyzing my old code and found I did not add anything on package.json so it could not be any other dependency.
When I found what was wrong it was silly as hell. I accidentally imported **Router** from **express** in a component

What was wrong

```
import { Router } from 'express';
```

What should be

```
import { Router } from '@angular/router';
```

Comment: Thank you @biswarup, I made the same mistake of importing Router from express.

Comment: Thanks so much! Didn't even realise I had also done this. Ty!

Comment: Thanks. - in my case there was other import from Express in Angular Service File.

Answer (score 2):

Check your App and make sure it has not auto imported a package that isn't supposed to be there.

I had this issue just today. The reason was sometimes it auto imports package when we are using, I was sending a fetch request and it auto imported {JSON, Express}.

So if you are somehow mixing backend packages with in src folder for front-end, this causes the issue.