# Retrieve 404 status when route is not found. Angular 6+ and Universal

Tags: angular, search-engine, angular-universal

I have released my project using Universal and specified in .htaccess that all requests should go to index.html (root page of the Angular application)

as it was asked here: 
https://angular.io/guide/universal

it allows sharing a link and to open a component specified in a URL

Also, created a component in case if an incorrect route is opened:
[Handling 404 with Angular2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34227194/handling-404-with-angular2)

```
export const routes:RouterConfig = [
  ...Routes,
  // Show the 404 page for any routes that don't exist.
  { path: '**', component: Four04Component }
];
```

The problem is that search engines treat the Four04Component as a simple page with 200 OK status rather an error page. Do you know how can retrieve a 404 error together with the Four04Component?

Comment: Found: https://www.thecodecampus.de/blog/angular-universal-handle-404-set-status-codes/

Trying to check

Comment: it doesn't work for Angular 6+ :(

Answer (score 7):

You have to inject Response into your angular app , to achieve that first change these lines in your `server.ts` :

```
app.get('*', (req, res) => { //you can find these line easily
res.render('index', {
    req: req,
    res: res,
    providers: [
        {
            provide: REQUEST, useValue: (req)
        },
        {
            provide: RESPONSE, useValue: (res)
        }
    ]
    });
});
```

Then in your **Four04** component inject response like this :

```
constructor(@Optional() @Inject(RESPONSE) private response: Response,
            @Inject(PLATFORM_ID) private platformId: Object) {}
```

After that simply try something like this on ngoninit of **Four04** component :

```
ngOnInit(){
    if(isPlatformServer(this.platformId)){
        this.response.status(404);
    }
}
```

Hope these help someone.

Comment: Thank you, Mohammed for that but it seems to me 
this.response.status(404); is no longer allows to set status via a function

Comment: I see this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50841139/modules-not-found-when-using-express

because of import { Response } from 'express';

Comment: What exactly do you want to achieve ? the above solution is for SEO and your document will generate 404 error when your 404 page loads .

Comment: I am using it now on my project , and it works perfectly fine , just remember that cause Response is not defined in browser you have to check via isPlatformServer then use it . i am using angular 7.2.5 .

Comment: @DenisEvseev try `this.response.statusCode = 404;`, you should not need to import anything

Comment: Is it possible without using SSR?

Comment: @PardeepJain the router redirect is possible without SSR, but from everything I've done SEO is not possible without SSR, which was the questions intent.  I'm not 100% sure but I also do not think the 404 error generation will work as well since you need to update the server.ts file.

Answer (score 0):

With Angular 17 and the SSR-Server, you may need some more:

Source: [angular-migrations/replace-nguniversal-engines](https://github.com/angular/angular-cli/blob/main/packages/schematics/angular/migrations/update-17/replace-nguniversal-engines.ts#L135-L199)

- create a file `express.tokens.ts` in `/src/`

  ```
  import { InjectionToken } from '@angular/core';
  import { Request, Response } from 'express';

  export const REQUEST = new InjectionToken<Request>('REQUEST');
  export const RESPONSE = new InjectionToken<Response>('RESPONSE');
  ```
- add `import { REQUEST, RESPONSE } from './src/express.tokens';` to your `server.ts`
- add `{ provide: REQUEST, useValue: req}, { provide: RESPONSE, useValue: res}` to the list of your providers passed to angular in the render opts in `server.ts`
- create the PageNotFoundComponent with its wildcard route like described in the [angular docs](https://angular.io/guide/router-tutorial#adding-a-404-page)
- ajust the `page-not-found.component.ts`

  ```
  import {Component, inject, PLATFORM_ID} from '@angular/core';
  import {RESPONSE} from "../../express.tokens";
  import {Response} from "express";
  import {isPlatformServer} from "@angular/common";

  @Component({
    selector: 'app-page-not-found',
    standalone: true,
    imports: [],
    templateUrl: './page-not-found.component.html',
    styleUrl: './page-not-found.component.scss'
  })
  export class PageNotFoundComponent {
    response: Response|null = inject(RESPONSE, {optional: true})
    platformId: Object = inject(PLATFORM_ID)

    ngOnInit(){
      if(isPlatformServer(this.platformId) && this.response){
        this.response.status(404);
      }
    }
  }
  ```

More helpful links:

- https://garage.sekrab.com/posts/replacing-angular-universal-with-ssr-version-17-0
- https://blogit.create.pt/pedrolopes/2022/05/05/handling-not-found-routes-in-angular/
- https://gitlab.com/biletado/frontend/assets/angular/-/commit/669246e3eba38cf8ac52d5986484c6a19533cbdf